# Problems with csv file and rows

Tags: csv, pandas, rows

I have csv file. Rows looks like this:

"9895730293300317768    1901262 10000   3   1   13384   14221   2812679 2265117 0   1521|1263   1263    1263|149|15|11|3736 90|1027|1572|264|1|1263|196|374|264|1|8|196|2|1263  NULL    NULL"

I need to divide them into columns. But when I try to do this, I get this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bjFf.png)
Someone can help me, please? I tried everything that I found on the forum, I did not succeed.

Comment: What is your delimiter?

Comment: I think my delimiter should be this symbol |. At the same time there are spaces between the numbers and at the end of the line can be NULL.

Comment: so parameter `sep='|'` and `header=None` ? Are you sure it is desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Please few steps as follows -
1.Open in notepad
2.Replace '|'(pipe) with ',' (comma)
3.save it with .csv extension.

or 
1.Open in notepad
2.save it with .xls extension & open MS-Excel.